# Tool for drawing bezier lines - inspector for the length of the line

Tags: graphics, image-editing, drawing

Looking for a tool what allow me:

- draw shapes with bezier lines
- the inspector shows the **length** of the line

For example OmniGraffle allows draw a shape with bezier lines, but it doesn't show the length of the line e.g. for the following image omnigraffle show shows only the width and height of the bounding box.

[image]

**I need the length of the line.**

Any such tool?

Answer (score 1):

Just found:

The Inkscape could measure the path length:

- select the path
- click `Extension` -> `Visualise path` -> `Measure path`

It will attach the length of the path into image. Not the native OS X app (needs X.org), but works OK, and it is free.